# How do I plot a 2D function with an intermediate variable?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics

I have a function
$c\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 10^{-6.367}*x + 10^{-6.367-10.32}} + x = c\cdot\frac{10^{-6.367-10.32}}{x^2 + 10^{-6.367}*x + 10^{-6.367-10.32}}+\frac{10^{-14}}{x}$, where $0 < x < 10^{-7}$.
I want to plot of $y = c\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 10^{-6.367}*x + 10^{-6.367-10.32}}$ and $z = \frac{10^{-14}}{x}$ vs $x$, and I try

```
ContourPlot[{x + c*x^2/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32)) 
== 10^-14/x + c*y, y == 10^(-6.367 - 10.32)/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32))}, {c, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But it seems that `ContourPlot` can't involve an intermediate variable, then I try to plot

```
ContourPlot[{x + c*x^2/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32)) 
== 10^-14/x + c*10^(-6.367 - 10.32)/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32))}, {c, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

, it doesn't work, too.
so how can I plot such a function?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns[x_] = {
     x + c*x^2/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32)) == 
      10^-14/x + c*y,
     y == 
      10^(-6.367 - 10.32)/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32))} //
     Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify[#, x > 0 && c >= 0] &;

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns[x],
  {c, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"c", "y"}),
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{x, 5.*10^-7}, 1.*10^-8, 1.*10^-6, 1.*10^-8, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
eqns2[y_] = {
     x + c*x^2/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32)) == 
      10^-14/x + c*y,
     y == 
      10^(-6.367 - 10.32)/(x^2 + x*10^-6.367 + 10^(-6.367 - 10.32))} //
     Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify[#, x > 0 && c >= 0] &;

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns2[y],
  {c, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 0.0006},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"c", "x"}),
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{y, 0.995}, 0.9, 1, 0.001,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.